# Syntax error before '*' token

Tags: c, syntax

```
int main() {
    return 0;
}

const uint8_t* byteHunter(const uint8_t *Search, uint16_t sLength, 
                          const uint8_t *Pattern, uint16_t pLength) { 
    // This is the body of the function
}
```

I get an error when compiling this function interface that says:

```
19 C:\Users\Anne\Documents\School\Sophomore\Spring2012\CS 2505\HW09.c syntax error before '*' token
```

Besides comments above the function interface, there is nothing else in my code at all. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Or, if you're going to need macros for format specifiers, `#include <inttypes.h>` which also includes the `<stdint.h>` header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type `uint8_t` is "unknown" by default, unless you `#include <stdint.h>` which will declare to the compiler what `uint8_t` really is.

Answer (score 0):

it might not know the `uint8_t` type. include `<stdint.h>` or wherever `uint8_t` is defined.

Answer (score 0):

In this case this clearly hints that there's something wrong with the part before the `*`. As there's a type named, it's most likely this type is unknown to the compiler right now, which will most likely be caused by some header file you forgot to include.

In this case you'll either have to include `stdint.h` (recommended) or somehow define the type yourself (using a typedef or preprocessor macro).